# Circular Dependency Error with Auth0

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning authentication using an Angular and Auth0 video on Udemy.

I've gotten to the point where I'm handling 401 errors and I'm receiving the following error:

```
angular.js:66 Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: auth <- redirect <- $http <- auth
```

And here is my angular configuration:

```
angular.config(config);

function config($provide, authProvider,
    $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $httpProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider) {

    authProvider.init({
      domain: 'cmckinstry.auth0.com',
      clientId: 'Rmdm7tgPIWv1e1P6sKrBDoW8zI4kuOEa'
    });

    jwtInterceptorProvider.tokenGetter = function(store) {
      return store.get('id_token');
    }

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'components/home/home.tpl.html'
      })
      .state('profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'components/profile/profile.tpl.html',
        controller: 'profileController as user'
      });

    function redirect($q, $injector, auth, store, $location) {
      return {
        responseError: function(rejection) {
          if (rejection.status === 401) {
            auth.signout();
            store.remove('profile');
            store.remove('id_token');
            $location.path('/home');
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      }
    }

    $provide.factory('redirect', redirect);

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('redirect');
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
  }
```

So, taking out the `auth` injection from the `redirect` function. But, then the redirect doesn't work properly. I'm suspecting that this has something to do with the `authProvider`, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Why did you include the `$injector` service in the `redirect` function when you don't use it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message:

> Circular dependency found: `auth <- redirect <- $http <- auth`

As stated in the error message, the circular dependency is formed because the authProvider uses the httpProvider which then uses the redirectProvider which completes a circle with the authProvider.

To break the circle, don't inject `auth` as a dependency in the redirectProvider construction function. Use the [$injector service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$injector) to inject the `auth` service when it is needed.

```
$provide.factory('redirect', redirect);
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('redirect');

//function redirect($q, $injector, auth, store, $location) {
function redirect($q, $injector, store, $location) {
  return {
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if (rejection.status === 401) {
        //INJECT HERE
        var auth = $injector.get("auth");
        auth.signout();
        store.remove('profile');
        store.remove('id_token');
        $location.path('/home');
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  }
}
```